# c++ reference variable speed difference with other variable

Tags: c++, reference

If I use the reference variable

```
int &ret = buffer[balance];
```

while solving the online judge problem, the timeout(limit: 2s) does not occur.

When I use the general variable,

```
int ret = buffer[balance];
```

timeout occurs and I wonder why.

this is my code using reference variable

```
#define INF 123456789

int coins[100]; // 사용가능한 동전들
int n; // 동전 가짓수
int k; // 총 합

int buffer[10001]; // 금액에 맞는 최소값

int check(int balance) {
    if (balance < 0)
        return INF;

    if (balance == 0)
        return 0;

    int &ret = buffer[balance];

    if (ret != -1)
        return ret;

    ret = INF;

    // 가능한 모든 코인에 대해서 반복
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
    }

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    // initialization
    memset(buffer, -1, sizeof(buffer));

    cin >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &coins[i]);
    }

    int ret = check(k);

    if (ret == 0 || ret == INF)
        ret = -1;
    cout << ret << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

using general variable

```
int check(int balance) {
    if (balance < 0)
        return INF;

    if (balance == 0)
        return 0;

    int ret = buffer[balance];

    if (ret != -1)
        return buffer[balance];

    ret = INF;

    // 가능한 모든 코인에 대해서 반복
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
    }

    if(ret < INF)
        buffer[balance] = ret;

    return ret;
}

int main() {
    // initialization
    memset(buffer, -1, sizeof(buffer));

    cin >> n >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &coins[i]);
    }

    int ret = check(k);

    if (ret == 0 || ret == INF)
        ret = -1;
    cout << ret << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

here is disassembly code using reference

```
    int &ret = buffer[balance];
000B1B4B  mov         eax,dword ptr [balance]  
000B1B4E  lea         ecx,buffer (0BB2D0h)[eax*4]  
000B1B55  mov         dword ptr [ret],ecx  

    if (ret != -1)
000B1B58  mov         eax,dword ptr [ret]  
000B1B5B  cmp         dword ptr [eax],0FFFFFFFFh  
000B1B5E  je          check+5Ch (0B1B6Ch)  
        return buffer[balance];
000B1B60  mov         eax,dword ptr [balance]  
000B1B63  mov         eax,dword ptr buffer (0BB2D0h)[eax*4]  
000B1B6A  jmp         check+0C2h (0B1BD2h)  

    ret = INF;
000B1B6C  mov         eax,dword ptr [ret]  
000B1B6F  mov         dword ptr [eax],75BCD15h  

    // 가능한 모든 코인에 대해서 반복
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
000B1B75  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0  
000B1B7C  jmp         check+77h (0B1B87h)  
000B1B7E  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
000B1B81  add         eax,1  
000B1B84  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax  
000B1B87  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
000B1B8A  cmp         eax,dword ptr [n (0BB2C8h)]  
000B1B90  jge         check+0BDh (0B1BCDh)  
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
000B1B92  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
000B1B95  mov         ecx,dword ptr [balance]  
000B1B98  sub         ecx,dword ptr coins (0BB138h)[eax*4]  
000B1B9F  push        ecx  
000B1BA0  call        check (0B1393h)  
000B1BA5  add         esp,4  
000B1BA8  add         eax,1  
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
000B1BAB  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E0h],eax  
000B1BB1  mov         edx,dword ptr [ret]  
000B1BB4  push        edx  
000B1BB5  lea         eax,[ebp-0E0h]  
000B1BBB  push        eax  
000B1BBC  call        std::min<int> (0B12FDh)  
000B1BC1  add         esp,8  
000B1BC4  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ret]  
000B1BC7  mov         edx,dword ptr [eax]  
000B1BC9  mov         dword ptr [ecx],edx  
    }
000B1BCB  jmp         check+6Eh (0B1B7Eh)  

    return ret;
000B1BCD  mov         eax,dword ptr [ret]  
000B1BD0  mov         eax,dword ptr [eax]  
}
```

using general variable

```
    int ret = buffer[balance];
00EF1B52  mov         eax,dword ptr [balance]  
00EF1B55  mov         ecx,dword ptr buffer (0EFB2D0h)[eax*4]  
00EF1B5C  mov         dword ptr [ret],ecx  

    if (ret != -1)
00EF1B5F  cmp         dword ptr [ret],0FFFFFFFFh  
00EF1B63  je          check+61h (0EF1B71h)  
        return buffer[balance];
00EF1B65  mov         eax,dword ptr [balance]  
00EF1B68  mov         eax,dword ptr buffer (0EFB2D0h)[eax*4]  
00EF1B6F  jmp         check+0C1h (0EF1BD1h)  

    ret = INF;
00EF1B71  mov         dword ptr [ret],75BCD15h  

    // 가능한 모든 코인에 대해서 반복
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
00EF1B78  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],0  
00EF1B7F  jmp         check+7Ah (0EF1B8Ah)  
00EF1B81  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00EF1B84  add         eax,1  
00EF1B87  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax  
00EF1B8A  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00EF1B8D  cmp         eax,dword ptr [n (0EFB2C8h)]  
00EF1B93  jge         check+0BEh (0EF1BCEh)  
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
00EF1B95  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-18h]  
00EF1B98  mov         ecx,dword ptr [balance]  
00EF1B9B  sub         ecx,dword ptr coins (0EFB138h)[eax*4]  
00EF1BA2  push        ecx  
00EF1BA3  call        check (0EF1393h)  
00EF1BA8  add         esp,4  
        ret = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, ret);
00EF1BAB  add         eax,1  
00EF1BAE  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E4h],eax  
00EF1BB4  lea         edx,[ret]  
00EF1BB7  push        edx  
00EF1BB8  lea         eax,[ebp-0E4h]  
00EF1BBE  push        eax  
00EF1BBF  call        std::min<int> (0EF12FDh)  
00EF1BC4  add         esp,8  
00EF1BC7  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]  
00EF1BC9  mov         dword ptr [ret],ecx  
    }
00EF1BCC  jmp         check+71h (0EF1B81h)  

    return ret;
00EF1BCE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ret]  
}
```

thanks for read. please help me!

Comment: Because when you don't use a reference, the code ends up doing absolutely nothing whatsoever, and will keep doing absolutely nothing whatsoever until the end of time. Hence the timeout. No need to dig into the generated assembly. It has nothing to do with micro-level optimizations, but with the fact that this drastically changes the program's logic. References are fundamentally different from ...non-references.

Comment: Your code is doing something completely different when you use a reference. When you use a reference then you are modifying the contents of `buffer` via the reference `ret`. On the other hand if `ret` is a value, then the function does not modify the contents of `buffer`. That might explain different runtime, though I dont understand what `buffer` is good for to begin with

Comment: @user463035818 oh sorry, i just edit my question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `ret` is a reference, you're modifying the array through the reference and your code is equivalent to

```
int check(int balance) {
    if (balance < 0)
        return INF;

    if (balance == 0)
        return 0;

    if (buffer[balance] != -1)
        return buffer[balance];

    buffer[balance] = INF;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        buffer[balance] = min(check(balance - coins[i]) + 1, buffer[balance]);
    }

    return buffer[balance];
}
```

When `ret` is not a reference, you never update the array so `ret != -1` is never true.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with references you work with the same heap object.
I have made a quick drow for you to understand how a reference looks like :
[image: Referanes]

If you want to learn more please read this article: [Ref and Pointers](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html)